# Why does Srikalahasti Temple remain open during an eclipse?

Tags: shiva, history, temple, eclipse

As we all know, temples remain closed when there is an eclipse. But the [Srikalahasti temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srikalahasteeswara_temple) remains open even during eclipses and they also do special pujas on these occasions. Please share the story/reason behind this.

Comment: [This](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-andhrapradesh/srikalahasti-temple-remains-open/article1306461.ece) page has some info.

Comment: [Related but not duplicate] [Legend behind origin of Vayu Lingam in Srikalahasti and its meaning](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10820/3500)

Comment: I wasn't sure what your main question was, it seemed like you wanted to know why this particular temple remained open while others are closed. So I changed the tile to reflect the main question. If this is not what you meant, you can revert my edit and add some clarification.

Comment: There was an article in Telugu appeared in Eenadu (https://www.eenadu.net/aalayaalu/more/2/127392), which appears to be correct. @Mr_Green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SriKalaHasti is the temple popular for Kaal Sarp Dosh Nivaran and Rahu Ketu Puja. Since [Rahu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahu) and Ketu are attributed to be the reasons for the eclipse, this temple remains open during the eclipse.

During the eclipse, devotees offer puja to Rahu and Ketu to pacify them.

Comment: Sorry but actually, I was looking for a brief explanation. Though your answer is correct can you please extend it to explain "why it is famous for Kaal Sarp dosh Nivaran and rahu ketu puja?"