# Legend behind origin of Vayu Lingam in Srikalahasti and its meaning

Tags: shiva, scripture, temple

There are many legends behind Srikalahasti temple, which is one of the Panchaboota Kshetras. But none of these legends explain origin of Vayu Lingam which is believed to be "Swayambhu" (self-manifested).

Famous among of all legends is story of three staunch devotees "Sri (spider), Kala (serpent) and Hasti (elephant)". But this legend says that they worshiped already existed lingam. Same is the case with other stories such as Bhakta Kannappa, penance of Parvati and Markandeya.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Rudram_Chamakam) wiki page,

> It is said that Lord Shiva, after Bhasmasura was killed with the help
>   of Lord Maha Vishnu, performed the Tandava Dance and then performed
>   the "Rudra Yagna" for the betterment of humanity. The place where the
>   Rudra Yagna was performed is where the "Sri Kalahasti" Temple stands
>   now.

Does this dance of Rudra has anything to do with this temple?
What is the exact legend behind origin of SriKalaHasti temple?

What is the meaning of Vayu Lingam? At Arunachalam (Tiruvannamala), Lord Shiva appeared as "Jyoti" or fire column, so lingam there is called as Agni Lingam. Similarly, empty space at Chidambaram is worshiped as "Akasa Lingam". So, what is the meaning of "Vayu Lingam" at Srikalahasti temple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Offical website](https://web.archive.org/web/20150721115817/http://www.srikalahastidevasthanam.com/history.php) of Temple gives info of origin of Vayu Lingam in Telugu.

> ప్రపంచ ముదయించిన మొదటి రోజుల్లో వాయు దేవుడి కర్పూర లింగాన్ని భక్తి
>   శ్రద్దలతో పూజించి అనేక వేల సంవత్సరములు తపస్సు చేశాడని తెలియచున్నది.
>   ఆయన తపస్సు కు సాక్షాత్కరించిన పరమేశ్వరుడు ‘వాయుదేవా ‘ నీవు చలనం
>   గలవాడవయ్యును చలనం లేని భక్తితో నన్నింత కాలం ధ్యానించి చేసిన తపస్సుకు
>   ఆనందించాను. భక్తుడవు కనుక నీకు కావలసిన వరాలు ఇవ్వడానికి వచ్చాను. నీకు
>   కావలసిన వరాలు ఏమిటో కోరుకో యిస్తా అన్నాడు. అందుకు వాయు దేవుడు ‘స్వామి’
>   నేని ప్రపంచము నందు లేని తావంటూ లేకుండగను, పరమాత్మ చందంబున ప్రతి జీవి
>   యందు నేను ప్రధానమై యుండు లాగునను, నీ ప్రతిరూపమైన ఈ కర్పూర లింగము నా
>   పేరు పిలువబడునట్లు నాకు వరములను ప్రసాదింపు ‘అని దోసిలి పట్టాడు.
>
> సాంబ శివుడు సంతోషించి ‘ఓయీ ! నీవు అభిలషించిన ఈ మూడు వరములను కోరదగినవే.
>   నీ అభిమతము ననుసరించి నీవీ ప్రపంచమంతటను వ్యాపించి వుండువు. నీవు లేక
>   జీవరాశి బ్రతుక జాలదు. నా యీ లింగము ఇక మీద నీ పేరున వాయు లింగమని
>   ప్రఖ్యాతి గాంచి సమస్త సుర అసుర గరుడ గంధర్వ కిన్నెర కింపురుష సిద్ధి
>   సాధ్వి నరముని వరుల చేతను పూజాలందుకొని నని’ వరములిచ్చి అదృశ్య మయ్యెను.
>   నాటి నుండి ఈ క్షేత్ర మందలి కర్పూర లింగం వాయు లింగమను పేరున సమస్త లోకాల
>   వారిచే పూజ లందుకోoటుంది.
>
> Here's my rough translation.
>
> During early days of creation of world, Lord Vayu performed penance
>   for thousands of years to "Karpoora lingam" (Karpooram means camphor).
>   Due to his penance, Parameswara manifested before him and said, " O
>   Vayu Deva! Though you are dynamic in nature, you stayed here without
>   movement and did penance for me. I'm pleased with your penance. Ask
>   boons you wish". Lord Vayu asked, "Swami! I **want to be present
>   everywhere in this world. I want to be an integral part of every Jiva
>   who is none other than manifestation of Paramatma. I want to name this
>   Karpoora Linga, which represents you, after me.**
>
> Samba Siva said," Your are qualified for these three boons. As per
>   your wish, you will be spread throughout this world. Without you there
>   will be no life. **This linga of mine will be famous by your name** and
>   all Suras, Asuras, Garuda, Gaandharvas, Kinneras, kimpurushas,
>   Siddhas, Saadhvis, humans and others worship this Lingam". Lord Shiva
>   disappeared after granting these boons". Thereafter, this Karpoora
>   Vayu Lingam is worshiped by all Lokas.