# Mystery of Ancient Hindu Temples?

Tags: shiva, history, temple

Our Ancients built Hindu Temples in a Straight line (From Kedarnath to Rameswaram - all are Lord Shiva temples), at that time without having proper Maps and Satellite's how can they built in straight line? Our ancestors known about Earth Geometry or Any one helped?

Comment: You can connect any two points in a straight line. Is there a third or fourth or fifth? If not, what is the point of your question?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I think you have to understand a lot here. I'm saying it's one to another, it means not only two. In between there is nearly 7/8. If you understand my point please think about it, otherwise plz calm down.

Comment: The jyotirlingas have been compared to the chakras in our body. Not sure how tenable this theory is.

Comment: I think you are talking about some Quora post of Pancha Bhoota Kshetras of Shiva with Rameswaram. We follow Agama Sastras, Vastu Sastras for building Temples. Maybe answer lies there. Can you mention all temples which lie on Straight line?

Comment: you have only provided two geographical points. What other temples lie in your straight line? Have to researched this or are you only providing something that your auntie told you? Also, geometry is an ancient science of Indian culture - it is not a part of the Hindu religion.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, It is not related to Quora and I can provide link below: http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/from-kedarnath-to-rameswaram-7-ancient-shiva-temples-fall-in-straight-line-638811

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda please don't talk more other than related to question. No one told this to me, I found a video on YouTube. FYI, Hinduism is not only a religion it's more about our believes/culture which is our ancestors want to share future generations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not that these temples were built by looking geometry of earth or using some advanced technology to map latitude and longitude.

These are Tirtha sthalas and they are not like modern day temples where they can be built anywhere (looking latitudes and longitudes). Tirthasthalas are those where some divine story happened there and temple is built at that place in the rememberance of that story and recognizing the special divinity residing there.

For example:

> **Kedarnath** is the place where Nara-Narayana established Shiva Linga as discussed in [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/what-is-the-story-of-kedarnath-jyotirlinga/14418#14418) Similarly in **Rameshwaram** Rama established Shiva Linga near Setu Bandha area as discussed in [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14349/what-is-the-story-of-rameshwaram-jyotirlinga/14350#14350). **Sri Kalahasti** is the place where Vayu established Shiva Linga as discussed in [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/legend-behind-origin-of-vayu-lingam-in-srikalahasti-and-its-meaning/10824#10824) And similarly all Tirtha sthalas are those place where some divine things happened there and thus temple is built there.

The point is these Temples aren't built by selecting such places where Latitude and Longitude matches. They are established where some divine story happened. So, there is no question of using some technologies to match latitude and longitude.

But how is it possible that they all came to lie on straight line? We can just say this is a divine coincidence and it's all Shiva's plan. So, the stories happened on particular place and temples were built there. It's all wish of Shiva.

Comment: thanks for answer, may be your examples small part of it but It's not% 100 true. There is something or some one (force) behind this, Why because I can give you an example "Varaha (third in the Dashavatara) slew the demon and retrieved the Earth from the ocean, lifting it on his tusks, and restored Bhudevi to her place in the universe". If it is not sphere or ellipsoid then Varaha can't lift, so I believe our Ancestors known earth Geometry and more advanced technologies far better than us.

Comment: @CR241 I certainly agree with you that our ancestors knew much things like I discuss some of them here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/what-are-some-scientific-facts-described-in-hindu-scriptures/17445#17445 But here in this case Temples are established there where divine story happens and not by calculating latitude longitude..

Comment: @CR241 Is there a list of temples we are talking about, which are at least approximately collinear?

Comment: @Tezz - Also there is a possibility that those temples /tirthas were built on pilgrimage root / travellers route ,which is some how is in a straight line.So that people could stop and see those temples also , while doing their journey to main destination.

Comment: @CR241 From Puranic perspective, these temple are built when divine events happened. This could be coincidence or there could be some esoteric meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Lord Siva Temples in India on almost same Longitude

1. Kedarnath – Kedarnath Temple (30.7352° N, 79.0669)
2. Kaleshwaram – Kaleshwara Mukteeshwara swamy Temple (18.8110, 79.9067)
3. Srikalahati – Srikalahasti Temple (13.749802, 79.698410)
4. Kanchipuram – Ekambareswarar Temple (12.847604, 79.699798)
5. Thiruvanaikaval – Jambukeswara Temple (10.853383, 78.705455)
6. Tiruvannamalai – Annamalaiyar Temple (12.231942, 79.067694)
7. Chidambaram – Nataraja Temple (11.399596, 79.693559)
8. Rameswaram – Ramanathaswamy Temple(9.2881, 79.3174)

**The five temples were built according to the yogic sciences, and are placed in a certain geographic alignment with each other, so that the entire region reverberated with the possibility they offered.**

Source : https://www.booksfact.com/mysteries/ancient-siva-temples-straight-line.html

Comment: "The five temples were built according to the yogic sciences, and are placed in a certain geographic alignment with each other, so that the entire region reverberated with the possibility they offered." Can you add authentic source, such as Agama or any Hindu scriptures, for this statement ?

Comment: https://www.booksfact.com/mysteries/ancient-siva-temples-straight-line.html

Comment: Differences might be due to oblate spheroid shape of the earth.