# Significance of 79 in Hinduism?

Tags: shiva

They all are located at 79° longitudes. What is surprising and awesome is that how the architects of these temples many hundreds of kilometers apart came up with these precise locations without GPS or any such gizmo like that.

1. Kedarnath 79.0669°
2. Kalahashti 79.7037°
3. Ekambaranatha- Kanchi 79.7036°
4. Thiruvanamalai 79.0747°
5. Thiruvanaikaval 78.7108
6. Chidambaram Nataraja 79.6954°
7. Rameshwaram 79.3129°
8. Kaleshwaram N-India 79.9067°

What is the significance of 79 ?

Comment: It comes before 80 :-). Though on a serious note , you may want to modify the question and ask why are these places in same longitude. These places existed long before latitudes and longitudes as a way to mark locations came into existence

Comment: 37,19,37.019888

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mystery of Ancient Hindu Temples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/mystery-of-ancient-hindu-temples)

Comment: latitudes and longitudes were designated by the English, with the prime meridian (0 degrees longitude) being Greenwich, England. Not a question about Hinduism.